# issue with __construct in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
! function (d, b, c, a) {
    Velop.AssignmentQuestionAnswerHandler = function (e) {
        this.__construct(e)
    };
    Velop.AssignmentQuestionAnswerHandler.prototype = {
        __construct: function (e) {
            this.clientAction = Velop.resolveClientAction("client", true);
            this.sectionIdAction = XenForo.getAction("section");
            this.$input = e;
            this.assignmentQuestionControl = e.closest(".AssignmentQuestionAnswerHandler");
            this.$input.change(d.context(this, "save"));
            this.lastValue = null
        },
...
```

I saw above script in a js file.

Question:

what does this line mean? `__construct: function (e)` ? does this equal to `constructor: function (e)`? I saw `__construct` in php file, but i never saw it is used in js file.

Comment: `__construct` has no special meaning in Javascript, somebody simply chose that name.

Comment: There is no concept of constructor in JavaScript. It is only a function declaration using underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it is just an internal convention to separate the logic from the actual constructor function and to be able to call it as a method when needed. Other libraries use `_init` for example.

```
function Class(e) {
  this.__construct(e);
}
```

`__construct` on its own has no meaning in JavaScript. Plus it is inside an object where keys can be named anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some (strange) kind of constructor. With this.__construct, the constructor function is accessible from outside of the function.

normaly you flag internal function with an underscore... :)